# How to write physical units

Tags: units

I am writing my Master Thesis memory and I have come up with a doubt, how should I write 1 megahertz: 1MHz (without space) or 1 MHz (with space)?

I searched on the internet, on papers and books, and I have found it written in both ways. Which should I use?

Comment: one word: `siunitx`, it is with a small space (not word space)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about which notation to use. Questions about notation are only on-topic if you know which notation you need to write and you want to know how to render such a notation in LaTeX.

Comment: And, for your reference, https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf

Comment: Or https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2794/punctuation-with-units for a more informal explanation.

Comment: International standards are never wrong: https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/bibliography.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most secure way is to do it with `siunitx`: the macro `\SI{1}{\MHz}` will typeset it correctly, with a thin space between the number and the unit, and no space inside the unit.